# Is it possible to train a TensorFlow model converted from PyTorch via ONNX converter

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

I have trained the PyTorch model for the MNIST dataset and converted it into the onnx model and then loaded the model and through `onnx_tf.backend` converted into TensorFlow. But I wanted to know is it possible for me to train the TensorFlow model again.